# Timing issue while writing from a serial port

Tags: serial-port, timing

This question is going to be a bit vague and I apologize for that.

I have a system that is connected to a serial port and a Python script that communicates with it. The script runs the system, reads the data it outputs, writes a file with the data, stops the system and repeats the previous series of functions for a defined number of iterations. Apart from writing data from the system to the file, the scripts also logs the system time. Ideally, every "run" of the system should generate evenly spaced out (in time) data. I looked at the time stamps and plotted the difference between each of the data points and got this (Y-axis is time in mm:ss)
[image: Rate variation with iteration]
I want to somehow profile a section of the code for each iteration to figure out why those blips exist. Would it be possible that some background process is causing these anomalies? If so, how do I hone in what's going on at those points?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give some tips on how to home in on it. Don't know if they will help but at least something to work with.
First i would try to sort out if it's the python script or the connected system that hicks up occationally.
[Portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/portmon.aspx)
from sysinternals could be of good help here. If you are on windows that is.
With that you can see exactly what is sent and received on the serial port. Either you have a request response type protocol and the script requests chunks from the system. If you se a request go out and then no response for 2seconds then the device is our problem, not the script or the os. If something is wrong with the cabling or the serial port you could see this here as well.

If the script is your problem it really can be anything. The hickups seams regular. You can use that to your advantage. If you run it at half frequency. Does the hickups occur half as often? If so it's related to how many runs you make. Perhaps a leak of some sort. Do you close everything up when you start over? How do you schedule it? How precise is the scheduler? 2sec isn't that long time.
I don't know about profiling python but you could always just write to a log file with a timestamp for each step you're doing to find where the code halts.
Just a few pointers. hope it helps